# How to use the Materialize linear indeterminate progress bar as a page preloader?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, materialize

I'm using [Materialize Framework](https://materializecss.com/) in a personal project and I want to create a loading indicator using not the circular, but the linear progress bar and it's animation.

**PROBLEM**

While the circular animation works as expected while the screen is loading, the [linear indeterminate progress bar](https://materializecss.com/preloader.html) doesn't until the page is fully loaded.

I've had a **short peek** at the materialize.js file but I didn't find anything related to the progress bar "being activated" only when the page is fully loaded. Is there a way to change this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Circular and Linear Indeterminate preloaders don't have any logic attached to them - they just animate, looped, forever. It is down to the developer to show and hide as needed.

Here is an example of how you might use them in an ajax call - show when the call is triggered and then hide on success:

```
function ajax_function() {

    $('.preloader-wrapper').removeClass('hide');

    $.ajax({

        url : '.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            data: mydata

        },
        error : function( response ){      
            // Handle error
        },
        success : function( response ){

            if( response == 0 ) {

                // Handle no response

            } else {                    

                $('.mydiv').append( response );
                $('.preloader-wrapper').addClass('hide');


            }

        }

    })
}
```